# AWS Cpanel & Phpmyadmin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Can any please help me in below issue.
I am planning to host more than one site on single AWS ec-2 Instance, now I want every site have its own cpanel and phpmyadmin.

**Confusion**
should I need to install Cpanel and PHPMyAdmin for every site or what?

Maybe it a silly question but currently, I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

No .. the right thing is adding from "addon domain" menu on cpanel and then u have seperate root folder for your files and you can add extra database and user in "mysql databases" menu section on cpanel

Comment: Do you have cPanel/WHM already installed on your server or you plan to install it ?

Comment: Well thanks for being so short! What do you try to do in the end? If you have cPanel/WHM installed, each of the cpanel accounts has phpMyAdmin!

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using cPanel/WHM first you need to install the software on your server. You will be provided with a 15 days trial license and then you need to pay a monthly or yearly fee (around $15/month). Then from the WHM interface you can add cpanel accounts for your different domains. Each added cPanel account will have it's own login credentials (username/password) and a bunch of stuff to play with from editing files, creating emails, mysql database administration, phpmyadmin included etc.

If you do not plan to use cPanel at all then you need to configure your server the way you need or use any other hosting panels (some of them paid as Plesk for example) or free ones: ISPConfig, CWP, Virtualmin/Usermin, VestaCP etc.